# JPA - Max of VARCHAR column DB2

Tags: sql, jpa, db2

In JPA how to write the below DB2 query

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(ABC_COLUMN AS INT)) FROM ABC_TABLE
```

How to write this in a Named Query?
When I write this in the below piece of code as

```
@NamedQuery(name="getMaxValue", query="SELECT MAX(CAST(ABC_COLUMN AS INT)) FROM ABC_TABLE")
```

This statement is showing compilation error as CAST is not defined in the FROM Clause.

How to overcome this?

Comment: NamedQuery expects JPQL, not SQL. JPQL is a different language. It doesn't use tables and columns, but entities and their properties. Learn JPQL, or use SQL but make this a NamedNativeQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JB Nizet pointed, Once you go for vendor specific DB functions (like `CAST` in your example, you will have to use native queries

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. CAST is not vendor specific, and HQL supports CAST.